# Catching people removing Excel passwords

Tags: excel, passwords

I have several Excel files passworded in different ways.
Password on Open
Password on Sheet
Password on VBA
Password on workbook

I have search for hours and cannot find any vba that i can run on excel open & close to see if any of these passwords have been removed and send an email and clear everyhting from the workbook.
I have found people removing passwords with hex editors and was to put a stop to it.
Also somehow bypassing the vba protection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to convert the Excel files to Excel 2007 or newer.  These cannot have their passwords removed.

Comment: That's not the case for the VBA project password.